# Is Azure AD application proxy on Windows Server core?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to install and configure an Azure application proxy connector on windows server 2016 (Core), or does it only work on full (UI) server install?

Comment: It's possible. Here is a [tutorial](https://gotoguy.blog/2018/02/19/install-register-azure-ad-application-proxy-connector-on-windows-server-1709/) for the server core.

Comment: @NancyXiong - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible. The [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-add-on-premises-application#windows-server) states:

> To use Application Proxy, you need **a Windows server running Windows
>   Server 2012 R2 or later**. You'll install the Application Proxy
>   connector on the server.

It seems you only need a windows server 2012 R2 or above. You can try to install the Application Proxy connector with commands.

Here is a tutorial for server core: [Install & Register Azure AD Application Proxy Connector on Windows Server 1709](https://gotoguy.blog/2018/02/19/install-register-azure-ad-application-proxy-connector-on-windows-server-1709/)

More references:

- [What is the Server Core installation option in Windows Server?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/what-is-server-core)
- [Create an unattended installation script for the Azure AD Application Proxy connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-register-connector-powershell)